# Некорректное выполнение php-скрипта по cron

Tags: php, cron

Столкнулся со странным для меня явлением.

Есть php-скрипт, который при запуске выдёргивает некоторые значения из БД, формирует переменную и отправляет её значение через бота в Telegram.

Если скрипт запускать вручную через браузер, в Telegram прилетает сообщение целиком, как и задумано.

Если же скрипт запускается по cron, то в Telegram приходит сообщение без значения переменной.

В cron прописано следующее:

```
59 23 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/myhost.ru/public_html/_tze/cron_script.php
```

Код скрипта:

```
$message = "Повестка дня:\r\n";
$i=1;

$_tasks = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `title` FROM `tze_tasks` ");
while ($tasks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($_tasks) )
    {
        $message = $message."\r\n".$i.". ".$tasks['title'];
        $i++;
    } 

file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot276781699:AAFY6PZ7icBbHP1XZS582Pt
RzHGhoPezb6U/sendMessage?chat_id='.$chat_id.'&text='.urlencode($message));
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Как вы вызываете скрипт? Добавьте строку

Comment: 59 23 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/myhost.ru/public_html/_tze/cron_script.php

Comment: переменная, небось, создаётся http-сервером. значит, запускайте скрипт не интерпретатором `php`, а запросом к http-серверу через браузер: `wget`, `curl` и т.п.

Comment: Проблема в скрипте. Где-то. Но скрипт секретный. Потому ничем вам помочь не смогут

Comment: Код скрипта покажите. То место, где переменная определяется и используется

Comment: На самом деле помог ответ alexander barakin: запуск через curl спасает.

Comment: Это костыль, а не "спасает": вы лишь зарыли проблему поглубже, типа всё устраивает. Код надо было показывать, разбираться надо было.

Comment: @AK Добавил код. Благодарю за подсказки, ибо я человек начинающий и даже понятия "костыль" и "правильно написанный скрипт" иногда путаю. Но готов внимать.

Comment: @AK, выложенный скрипт явно не предназначен для запуска в режиме «standalone» (используется подключение к базе данных, которое происходит где-то в недрах сайта), а потому остаётся единственный **разумный** выход — использовать браузер и обращение к http-серверу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а если подключение внести в этот же скрипт? Насколько это хорошее решение? Сделать так можно запросто. Но в данном случае тогда становится интереснее понять, какое решение будет более правильным и изящным :)

Comment: @user229633 Судя по скрипту, написано совершенно без учёта возможности запуска php_cli --  тут можно как рекомендовать подобную доработку, так и оставить костыль с запуском через wget. Если программирование -- не ваша профессия, можете остановиться на варианте, который Александр описал. Если вы программист, то можете написать вариант скрипта, который будет работать в обоих режимах. Чем больше в системе звеньев -- тем больше риск, что где-то сломается. Пусть даже это надёжный wget и интернет тут особо не нужен. (Что-нибудь накрутят в правилах firewall'а -- а вы будете гадать, что поломалось.)

Comment: @AK программирование не профессия, а хобби, которое, однако, мне интересно, и роста в этой области хочется.

Коллеги, ещё раз благодарен за подсказки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**обновление** в связи с выложенным содержимым скрипта: он явно не предназначен для запуска в режиме «standalone» (используется подключение к базе данных, которое происходит где-то в недрах сайта), а потому остаётся единственный разумный выход — использовать браузер и обращение к http-серверу, т.е. вариант номер два из предложенных ниже.

---

> без значения переменной

отсюда можно сделать вывод, что речь идёт про одну из множества переменных окружения, устанавливаемых http-сервером перед вызовом интерпретатора `php`.

выхода два:

1. можно указать эту переменную и её значение при вызове интерпретатора:

   ```
   имя=значение /usr/bin/php ...
   ```
2. а можно обращаться к интерпретатору не напрямую, а через http-сервер каким-нибудь «браузером» — `wget`, `curl` и т.п.:

   ```
   wget -qO /dev/null http://ваш.сервер/ваш.скрипт.php >/dev/null 2>&1
   ```

Comment: Выход на самом деле один: написать нормально скрипт, с учётом обоих возможных режимов запуска. А эти оба два варианта - это чистой воды костыли. Впрочем, если лишний оверхед на запуск wget не жалко и "пипл хавает" - пусть будет.

Answer (score -1):

Может быть нужно в начале скрипта добавить:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

но тогда он не будет запускаться через браузер

Comment: Согласен с минусовавшим: ваш ответ неправильный. Вы уже вызываете через php filename.php - и от простановки обработчика ничего не поменяется.

Comment: @AK, «минус», кстати, поставил «дух сообщества» после внесения правки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin А, я-то подумал, что ваш минус.